# How to make Element.scrollIntoView() on Chromium-based browsers not depend on smooth-scrolling flag?

Tags: javascript, chromium, smooth-scrolling

I have a JavaScript function that attempts to smoothly scroll an element into view:

```
dom_element.scrollIntoView({
    'behavior': 'smooth',
    'block': 'nearest'
});
```

On Firefox, this works perfectly fine.

But I realized that scrolling was instant, i.e. not respecting `behaviour': 'smooth'` on Chromium-based browsers (Chrome, Opera, Brave).

Both MDN and caniuse.com showed that Chrome supported `behaviour: smooth`, so I was quite puzzled.

After a frustrating hour of debugging, I realized that the code works if I specifically go to `chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling` and toggle *Smooth Scrolling* from *Default* to *Enabled*. After some experimentation, I deduced that a value of *Default* for Smooth Scrolling meant *Disabled*.

The strange thing was: on another computer (laptop), the above code worked as expected without needing to tweak *Smooth Scrolling*. It was left as default, and scrolling was smooth.

Both PCs run the latest Chrome v83.0.4103.61 on Win 10 Pro.

Questions:

1. Why is the default setting for the *Smooth Scrolling* flag different for two computers? If hardware matters, one is a desktop i7-6700K with nVidia 1060GT, and the other is a laptop i7-8550U with GeForce MX110.
2. Since it's impractical to tell users to enable this flag before using the site, is it possible to override this flag programmatically in JS?

A snippet that demonstrates this problem for *some* PCs on Chrome:

```js
let dom_target = document.querySelector('#target');

// Make clicks anywhere scroll smoothly to target (number 14)
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    dom_target.scrollIntoView({
        'behavior': 'smooth',
        'block': 'nearest'
    });
});
```

```css
#container {
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 100px;
}

#target {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Clicking anywhere scrolls to 14, and the scrolling behavior should be smooth.</h1>
<section id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item" id="target">14</div>
  <div class="item">15</div>
  <div class="item">16</div> 
</section>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE] where you'd face that issue? Hard to investigate without it. For instance, does[this minimal setup](https://jsfiddle.net/gu7m9sxa/) reproduces the issue? What about [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/gu7m9sxa/1/)?

Comment: I have added a snippet that triggers the problem on this computer's Chromium browsers. It works fine on Firefox.

Comment: ... Works in my Win10 VM (macOs does't even have that flag)

Comment: The code works fine. I tested on Chrome v83.0.4103.97 and Opera v68.0.3618.125 on Win10 Pro. Even `Smooth Scrolling` is set to default. Have you tried it on a fresh install (either windows or chrome)

Comment: I've not tried a fresh Windows install. I'd want to avoid doing that as much as possible. On this problematic machine, I have tried other Chromium-based browsers, though (Opera, Brave), and they behave the same as Chrome. This leads me to think it could be a Chromium or Windows setting.

Comment: Maybe the CSS [`scroll-behavior`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) rule helps?

Comment: @yunzen thanks for the suggestion. Tried it, doesn't work :(

Comment: @light What do you mean by 'tried it': What did you try? What do you mean by 'doesn't work'? What did not work?

Comment: "Tried it" literally means I added ```scroll-behavior: smooth``` to CSS of the container I'm trying to scroll, as your "Maybe" comment suggests that I do. If your comment did not mean to add that line of CSS, please clarify what it means. "Doesn't work" literally means the problem I described in the question still exists even after I added the line of CSS.

Answer (score 7):

You can't.<sup>1</sup>

This is controlled by an accessibility setting that you can trigger from the "*Show animations in Windows*" setting in Windows "Settings > Ease of Access > Display".

This being an **accessibility** feature from the OS, the browser won't let your website override it.

*(Also note that the flag you mentioned [might get removed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468754) in favor of letting only this setting control this behavior, so it may not even be a possible workaround in the future)*.

But that shouldn't be a problem, since users with this setting certainly did set it for a good reason.

<sup>1: Of course you can make this manually, but really you shouldn't go against user's preferences.</sup>

Comment: I want to confirm that this disabled setting was effectively causing the smooth behavior to disappear in Chrome (and other Chrome-based browsers) running on Windows. Oddly, Firefox was ignoring this setting. I don't know the default that comes with a fresh Windows setup (since I don't remember having turned it off).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this approach in my project and it is working, I hope you find this helpful.

What you have to do is just remove the **'behavior': 'smooth',** from your file.
So your code should look like below:

```
let dom_target = document.querySelector('#target');

// Make clicks anywhere scroll smoothly to target (number 14)
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
dom_target.scrollIntoView({
    'block': 'nearest'
 });
});
```

And you just add the style **scroll-behavior: smooth** to your element with id **target**.

So your HTML file should be somewhat like this:

```
<h1>Clicking anywhere scrolls to 14, and the scrolling behavior should be smooth.</h1>
<section id="container">
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">5</div>
<div class="item">6</div>
<div class="item">7</div>
<div class="item">8</div>
<div class="item">9</div>
<div class="item">10</div>
<div class="item">11</div>
<div class="item">12</div>
<div class="item">13</div>
<div class="item" id="target" style="scroll-behavior:'smooth'">14</div>
<div class="item">15</div>
<div class="item">16</div> 
</section>
```

Please try this once and I hope you can resolve your problem.

Comment: It's working great!